# Retrieve WMS service from GeoWebCache with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, geowebcache, standalone

Ok guys, here we go !
For my needs, I basically added a **standalone version** of **GeoWebCache**.
After some configuration, the **GeoWebCache** retrieve the data from **GeoServer** using Capabilities.

Now, in my **OpenLayers** code, I would like to question **GeoWebCache** to retrieve my data, and not **GeoServer** (if it is possible).

For the moment, I have something like this (working) :

```
    var fond_carto = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Fond cartographique 2", 
        "http://179.172.277.77:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: 'departement',
            TILED: 'true'
        }
```

I tried stuff like that (not working) :

```
    var fond_carto = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Fond cartographique 2", 
        "http://179.172.277.77:8080/geowebcache/sevice/wms",
        {
            layers: 'departement',
            TILED: 'true'
        }
```

Is there a way to accomplish that ?
After some reading, I assume I'm a bit lost with this standalone version of **GeoWebCache**. It is written it works as a proxy between client (**OpenLayers**) and server (**GeoServer**). But I read that the TILED: 'true' option means that **GeoServer** will send the layers for tiling to **GeoWebCache**. As I desactivated the integrated version of **GeoWebCache** in **GeoServer**, and as my WMS request are still tiled, I assume this is true. But then it's not really a proxy.

Could it works as follow:

*openlayers => standalone geowebcache => geoserver => standalone geowebcache => openlayers*

Or it has to work that way :

*openlayers => geoserver => standalone geowebcache => geoserver => openlayers*

**Thanks for any tips or any clarifications :-) !**

## EDIT

After some more configuration in geowebcache.xml, I still have the error but I can add some details to help.
This is the URL of the request that is not displaying (pink tiles) :

```
http://179.172.277.77:8088/geowebcache/sevice/wms?LAYERS=departement&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=2.8125,48.515625,3.515625,49.21875&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256:8080/geowebcache/sevice/wms?LAYERS=departement&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=2.8125,48.515625,3.515625,49.21875&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256 :
```

and when I try to copy/paste this url, I got a GWC error :

```
400: Thread 35 Unknown layer departement. Check the logfiles, it may not have loaded properly.
```

I don't get why I got this error. Here's my geowebcache.xml description of the layer :

```
<wmsLayer>
  <name>departement</name>
  <mimeFormats>
    <string>image/gif</string>
    <string>image/jpeg</string>
    <string>image/png</string>
    <string>image/png8</string>
  </mimeFormats>
  <gridSubsets>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:4326</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
  </gridSubsets>
  <wmsUrl>
    <string>http://179.172.277.77:8080/geoserver/wms</string>
  </wmsUrl>
  <wmsLayers>aaz:departement</wmsLayers>
</wmsLayer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Geoserver Instance and GeoWebCache should be running on different ports if on the same machine.

Then your GeoWebCache end point should be something like:

```
http://179.172.277.77:PORT/geowebcache/service/wms?
```

The flow is **Openlayers => Standalone GeoWebCache => GeoServer**

EDIT: (For Additional Question)

You look like you are using workspace **aaz** so your reference to the layer in geoWebCache should be **aaz:departement** not **departement**

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this out, then I'll make a feed back.

Comment: Hmhmhm, it seems like it doesn't change anything. I guess I have some more thing to do/change into geowebcache configuration.

Comment: I am running the exact same scenario. Geoserver defaults to port 8080, you must make sure your geowebcache to a different port, say 8081 or port 80 if it is not in use, then you do not have to specify the port in the url.

Comment: I've improved, facing now a new error, I've edited my post.

Comment: I answered this, but you should have posted it as a new question per StackExcahange Etiquette. Please accept the answer and UpVote if it answered your original question then ask as a new question as the original question has been dealt with.

Comment: Ok, I'll post another question. But the previous error was not coming from the fact both were running on the same port. Same for the new error. For your edit, the layer name is described in the <wmsLayers>, not in the <name> (according to the example coming from the demo of GeoWebCache, you can input what you want inside the <name>. Anyway, thanks for answering me, it always worth to improve my knowledge :)

Comment: Well then you should post the solution in an answer so that others know and can benefit. That's the point of this site, not just say "Its fixed". Cheers

Comment: Yes I know, but it's not fixed, first problem was coming from wrong namespace, etc. Not really helpful for the others. The real problem's coming from my edit.